# How to design something like this?

Tags: animation

I am very eager to know what technology might been used to implement this piece of wonder:

[image]

Any idea?

I think, it's ray tracing. What do you think?

Comment: your question is too vague. "design", "implement" = the rendering only ? now there are several aspects in rendering: intersecting the shape, surface materials, volume materials, light transport... the strange thing here is that the caustics on the floor seems very accurate, but the glass aspect seem very non-physical. Anyway, yes, ray-based algorithms are involved at many place here.  Anyway people would more consider design = shape and motion. (+ textures, when present).

Comment: Do you mean the mathematical shape?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Graphics SE! As Fabrice's and joojaa's comments show it's not entirely clear what you're asking. Please include some more detail whether your question is about the rendering (refraction and caustics), or the geometry or something else. It might also help to include the source of the image.

Answer (score 2):

It does look like raytracing to me as well.  It could also possibly be ray marching, which would be easier to make the tubes with since ray marching is all based on distances from things (center of tube in this case).

Refraction is what's used to bend the light that goes through the tubes.

You are then just left with how to model the tubes. One way could be to use 3d bezier curves (:

This may not have been made in real time, but may have been rendered frame by frame and then assembled into the smooth "movie" you are showing.